# Matplotlib is printing the line plot twice/multiple times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scipy

What could be the problem if Matplotlib is printing a line plot twice or multiple like this one:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate 


def compute_integrated_spectral_response_ikonos(file, sheet):
    df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=sheet, header=2)

    blue = integrate.cumtrapz(df['Blue'], df['Wavelength'])
    green = integrate.cumtrapz(df['Green'], df['Wavelength'])
    red = integrate.cumtrapz(df['Red'], df['Wavelength'])
    nir = integrate.cumtrapz(df['NIR'], df['Wavelength'])
    pan = integrate.cumtrapz(df['Pan'], df['Wavelength'])


    plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(6, 4), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
    plt.plot(df[1:], blue, label='Blue', color='darkblue');
    plt.plot(df[1:], green, label='Green', color='b');
    plt.plot(df[1:], red, label='Red', color='g');
    plt.plot(df[1:], nir, label='NIR', color='r');
    plt.plot(df[1:], pan, label='Pan', color='darkred')
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)
    plt.xlabel('Wavelength (nm)')
    plt.ylabel('Spectral Response (%)')
    plt.title(f'Integrated Spectral Response of {sheet} Bands')
    plt.show()

compute_integrated_spectral_response_ikonos('Sorted Wavelengths.xlsx', 'IKONOS')
```

Here is my [dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YmTO2Gw0JoASdKNXBUa3tatEUX_S816X).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because plotting `df[1:]` is plotting the entire dataframe as the x-axis.

```
>>> df[1:]
     Wavelength      Blue     Green       Red       NIR       Pan
1           355  0.001463  0.000800  0.000504  0.000532  0.000619
2           360  0.000866  0.000729  0.000391  0.000674  0.000361
3           365  0.000731  0.000806  0.000597  0.000847  0.000244
4           370  0.000717  0.000577  0.000328  0.000729  0.000435
5           375  0.001251  0.000842  0.000847  0.000906  0.000914
..          ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
133        1015  0.002601  0.002100  0.001752  0.002007  0.149330
134        1020  0.001602  0.002040  0.002341  0.001793  0.136372
135        1025  0.001946  0.002218  0.001260  0.002754  0.118682
136        1030  0.002417  0.001376  0.000898  0.000000  0.103634
137        1035  0.001300  0.001602  0.000000  0.000000  0.089097

[137 rows x 6 columns]
```

The slice `[1:]` just gives the dataframe without the first row. Altering each instance of `df[1:]` to `df['Wavelength'][1:]` gives us what I presume is the expected output:

```
>>> df['Wavelength'][1:]
1       355
2       360
3       365
4       370
5       375

133    1015
134    1020
135    1025
136    1030
137    1035
Name: Wavelength, Length: 137, dtype: int64
```

**Output:**

[image]